# Memory release issue in image upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to upload image data to a server.  They upload successfully, but I am seeing peaks in memory usage on each image upload. Also, uploading more than 20 images gets the app shut down and causes memory warnings.

Here is the code for the image upload.

```
NSDictionary * param =@{......};

manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 1200 ;// timeout for the bulk images
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];// set content type 
[manager POST:@"http://192.168.192.102:8080/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" parameters:param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
    for (int j = 0; j< imageData.count; j++)
    {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData[j] name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j+1] fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",j] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];// add multipart data to request

    }

} progress:^(NSProgress * uploadProgress) {
    NSLog(@"%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);// for how much upload it to server

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");// success of the image upload

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * error) {
    NSLog(@"fail%@", error.localizedDescription);// error in the image upload
}];
```

Comment: Do you want to submit one image per request of bulk of images in one request ? Currently from your code it looks like you submits bulk of images in a request using for....loop. How many times you call this request then ? one time or more than one time ? Once you append data to request try freeing up `imageData` variable, and it would be good if you limit the size of images.

Comment: one time.
but when we increase the no. of images it also increase the memory size..

Comment: and also if we are using good quality of images then it increase memory in the multiple of 10 mb per image....

Comment: You should first limit the dimension of the image to upload and downsize the image by either cropping or resizing, say downsize image from 1080x 1920 to 300xHeightWithAspectRatioOf300. This will minimize the data to sent. Also, instead of sending 10- 20 images in one request you can limit them to say 5 at a time release them after upload then another request with 5 more OR make a zip file of the bunch of images and upload this bunch on server.

Comment: I have done with that

Comment: I uploaded the image with 300*300 also i try to send the image in group but problem is same

Comment: It takes too much of memory as the size of image increase the memory size also increaes ..

Answer (score 0):

I used it with xCode 7 and iOS 9:-

```
-(void)uploadImages
    {
        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager POST:@"Your URL" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            int x=0;
            for (UIImage *imag in __chosenImages)
            {
                NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self resizeImage:imag]);
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"images[]" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",x] mimeType:@"image/png"];
                x++;
            }

        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject );
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
    }
    -(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image
    {
        float actualHeight = image.size.height;
        float actualWidth = image.size.width;
        float maxHeight = 800.0;
        float maxWidth = 800.0;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth/maxHeight;
        float compressionQuality = 1.0;//50 percent compression

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth)
        {
            if(imgRatio < maxRatio)
            {
                //adjust width according to maxHeight
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
                actualHeight = maxHeight;
            }
            else if(imgRatio > maxRatio)
            {
                //adjust height according to maxWidth
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
                actualWidth = maxWidth;
            }
            else
            {
                actualHeight = maxHeight;
                actualWidth = maxWidth;
            }
        }

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        [image drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    }
```

Comment: it is also taking more memory 
as the number of images increase it increase the memory also ...